# ASP.NET Web Service example with jQuery UI Sortable serialize method

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am building jQuery UI sortable to store order in the database using serialize and ASP.NET Web Service.

I know how to do it in php, but I am not sure how to do it in ASP.NET... I tried googling with little success.

```
   $('#mylist').sortable({
        handle: ".handle",
        axis: "y",
        update: function () {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            alert(order);
        }
    });
```

Gives me query string `item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4`

I need to pass that into Web Service, and store the new order into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i think is execute the code below

```
$('#mylist').sortable({
    handle: ".handle",
    axis: "y",
    update: function () {
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    }
});
```

which gives array of id's in the order they appear. Now when u save and get this array back do this.
//psedocode

```
for each id in the arrayList
GetElementByid(id); attach to parent UL
```

at last if u see, the list will be arranged as previous states

Answer (score 1):

[Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/2008/06/26/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/) has a series of posts that can start you in the right direction.